# Installing TU Darmstadt Design with mactex on os x sierra

Tags: fonts, errors, installing, mac

I'm trying to install tu Darmstadt fonts.

I followed directions on http://exp1.fkp.physik.tu-darmstadt.de/tuddesign/Mac_OS_X.html

Here's what happened. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That suspiciously looks like TeX Live/MacPorts. Not the best environment, I'm afraid.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Always paste text as text into a code block. Images cannot be copied, searched or pasted. It is not clear what kind of suggestions you hope to get as you don't say what problem, if any, you are facing. There is no error in the image you posted. We can't see the beginning because we can't scroll the picture of a scrollbar. The output says that `updmap-sys` thinks `Sch.map` is already in the configuration file. That is not MacTeX, which is strongly recommended on OS X.

Comment: I'm not making this into an answer because the original question is about Tex Live/MacPorts, but if it helps someone else, I have MacTeX on High Sierra and running `updmap-user --enable Map 5ch.map` instead of `updmap-sys` works for me.

Answer (score 2):

sorry for the inconvenience and repeating the question before. I just wanted to repeat it in text form and not as an Image.
But I solved the problem by using

```
$ updmap-user --force --enable Map 5ch.map
```

and it worked!